# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly... (.resources)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, package

On my ***ASP.NET Web API*** i have a method that parses some data from email messages using [MsgReader](https://sicos1977.github.io/MSGReader/). It works OK, but after a while it starts to throw following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MsgReader.resources, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=47f99f3a9a2648df' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MsgReader.resources, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=47f99f3a9a2648df' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at MsgReader.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody, MessageHeader headers) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Mime\MessagePart.cs:line 242
   at MsgReader.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent, Boolean parseBody) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Mime\Message.cs:line 139
   at MsgReader.Mime.Message.Load(Stream messageStream) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Mime\Message.cs:line 301
   at MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message.LoadClearSignedMessage(IStorage storage) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Outlook\Message.cs:line 1558
   at MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message.LoadStorage(IStorage storage) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Outlook\Message.cs:line 1384
   at MsgReader.Outlook.Storage..ctor(Stream storageStream, FileAccess fileAccess) in C:\Users\Kees\Documents\GitHub\MsgReader\MsgReader\Outlook\Storage.cs:line 196
   ...
```

After i recycle application pool, it works again (for a while) then at some time the error repeats...

I tried with assemblyBinding

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MsgReader" publicKeyToken="47f99f3a9a2648df" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.3.0" newVersion="2.1.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but no success...

I think the problem the problem is with Culture? Because as i see in error the Culture is en-US, but in ***MsgReader package*** there are only these cultures:

[image]

This is the part of the code where the exception is thrown:

```
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName)?.Replace(".", "").ToLower();
if (ext == "eml")
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var msg = new MsgReader.Mime.Message(datoteka.Bytes);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "DateSent",
                msg.Headers.DateSent.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
            .Save(connection);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "From", msg.Headers.From.Raw)
            .Save(connection);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "To",
                string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.To.Select(x => x.Raw)))
            .Save(connection);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Cc",
                string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.Cc.Select(x => x.Raw)))
            .Save(connection);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Bcc",
                string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.Bcc.Select(x => x.Raw)))
            .Save(connection);
        new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Subject", msg.Headers.Subject)
            .Save(connection);
    }
}
else if (ext == "msg")
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(datoteka.Bytes))
        using (var msg = new Storage.Message(stream))
        {
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "DateSent",
                    msg.Headers.DateSent.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
                .Save(connection);
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "From", msg.Headers.From.Raw)
                .Save(connection);
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "To",
                    string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.To.Select(x => x.Raw)))
                .Save(connection);
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Cc",
                    string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.Cc.Select(x => x.Raw)))
                .Save(connection);
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Bcc",
                    string.Join("; ", msg.Headers.Bcc.Select(x => x.Raw)))
                .Save(connection);
            new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "Subject", msg.Headers.Subject)
                .Save(connection);
            if (msg.SignatureIsValid != null)
                new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "SignatureIsValid",
                        msg.SignatureIsValid.Value
                            ? "true"
                            : "false")
                    .Save(connection);
            if (msg.SignedBy != null)
                new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "SignedBy", msg.SignedBy)
                    .Save(connection);
            if (msg.SignedOn != null)
                new HProperty(datoteka.ResourceId, "SignedOn",
                        msg.SignedOn.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
                    .Save(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the method that parses the data?

Comment: @Isma

    var fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName)?.Replace(".", "").ToLower();
    if (fileType == "msg")
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(file))
        using (var msg = new Storage.Message(stream))
        {
            ...

The error is thrown at this last line (using(var msg...)).

Storage is MsgReader.Outlook.Storage object.

Comment: Have you recently changed the .net version of the project?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic First I had the project on .NET 4.5, but because of this issue i upgraded to 4.6.2. I tought maybe it was a bug in .NET, but it didn't help...

Comment: This issue is not with how long the pool has been running but with a "weird" message you're passing into the library. According to the line numbers you're running into a null MessageHeader.

Comment: But if i recycle application, the same mail works again...

Comment: @StefanSchmiedl but when i recycle application pool, the same message starts working again. And also all other messages that previously worked stop working. Could it be something with Culture? The exception says it failed to load .resources for "Culture=en-US", but there is no such culture in MSGReader.

Comment: @MihaJerič The "cultural problem" only becomes relevant when the exception tries to find some message (and fails). Your real problem is not the missing message but that somehow your code loses track of the messages it is working on, hence the null MessageHeader.

Comment: @StefanSchmiedl but then why the same message works if i try it again? Could it be because of two using()'s, the MemoryStream is disposed while parsing or something like that?

Comment: @MihaJerič without having seen your code, I can only guess. It could very well be something like that, as it seems to happen "randomly".

Comment: @StefanSchmiedl I have edited my post so you can see entire parsing method. I went through MSGReader code, and i saw there are a lot of static methodts, or even properties. I am assuming this could be the problem, since it is not wise to use static on web services?

Comment: @MihaJerič If you follow the call chain in the backtrace, you see that an exception is thrown at Mime\MessagePart.cs, line 243. Assuming that the online line numbers match those in your code, this implies that `headers == null`. headers is the value of the `out` parameter `headersTemp` in Mime\Message.cs, line 130. The method in Mime\Header\HeaderExtractor.cs is `static`, but at first glance it only uses local variables and arguments, so its usage should be as thread-safe as its callers are. I would double-check the contents of `datoteka.Bytes` first. Are they still good if the file is gone?

Comment: Similar error in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707339/concurrency-issue-when-loading-satellite-assembly